# How to override fish_prompt, keeping the styles from the applied theme?

Tags: shell, fish

I installed fish shell, installed few themes. Applied the theme "agnoster", all good is pretty but I want fish_prompt to override the original one and keep the styles in order to show me full path properly. Currently the full path is a shortcut such as `Desktop/Abba` turns to `~D/Abba` and I want to remove the D and will it be `~Desktop/Abba`. How can I override `function fish_prompt` properly so that I am able to call the original previous function from the theme to keep up the styles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The agnoster theme uses fish's `prompt_pwd` function to display the pwd.

That shortens each path component to $fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length characters. Set that variable to 0 to inhibit shortening entirely.

Alternatively, you can change the prompt_pwd function however you want it, e.g. via `funced prompt_pwd` (and `funcsave prompt_pwd` once you're happy with the result).

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue, but the chosen answer didn't work for me.
In my case, I've had to source all theme files manually before overriding the `fish_prompt` function.

For example

```
source $OMF_PATH/init.fish # assure omf is loaded before run the following code

# Read current theme
test -f $OMF_CONFIG/theme
  and read -l theme < $OMF_CONFIG/theme
  or set -l theme default

set -l theme_functions_path {$OMF_CONFIG,$OMF_PATH}/themes*/$theme/functions/
for conf in $theme_functions_path/*.fish
  source $conf
end

function fish_prompt
  # prompt_theme_foo
  # prompt_theme_bar
end
```

More details on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72098697/2180456